nginx how to use expires with cache-control: public
I'd like to set the following header using nginx:
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800

My problem is that:

If I use expires, it adds only max-age
If I use add_header Cache-Control public, then it adds only public.
If I use both, then it adds two separate headers, both with the same "key":

cache-control: max-age=604800
cache-control: public

My questions:

Do I have to worry about anything, or it's good like this, defined in 2 separate headers?
If it's not good, how can I combine them into one?
Do I need public at all?


You can use add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=604800"; ? But per HTTP protocol, two headers with same name should be treated the same as one header with comma separated value https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-5.3

Thanks, also this one: https://http.dev/cache-control#multiple-directives
